# Get only last attribute value in XML List (Java)

Tags: java, xml, list, element

I have a problem with XML and JAVA, let me explain :

```
<xml> 
    <movies>
        <movie Detail="N" type="Horror" />
        <movie Detail="Y" type="Horror" />
    </movies>
</xml>
```

I want to get attribute Detail in this list of Movie, and after that I save this value in Value Object ( The part with Value Object is not interesting here)

Here this is how I get these values :

```
Element moviesElement = elementXml.getChild("movies");
List<Element> movieElements = moviesElement.getChildren("movie");
String detail= null;

for(Element movieElement : moviesElement) {
    detail= movieElement.getAttributeValue("Detail");
}
```

The problem is that it only retrieves the last value, I would like it to retrieve all the values, because I need it afterwards to check another condition

How can I do for get all values please , anyone have ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: You keep overwriting `detail`. Either do what you need to do to it inside the loop, or use a `List` to store all the values.

Comment: Yes: nothing to do with xml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store these results in collection like List, please see:

```
Element moviesElement = elementXml.getChild("movies");
List<Element> movieElements = moviesElement.getChildren("movie");
List<String> details= new ArrayList();

for(Element movieElement : moviesElement) {
    details.add(movieElement.getAttributeValue("Detail"));
}

//this will print every detail in details
for(String detail: details) {
    System.out.println(detail);
}
```

Without collection you are overriding you values.